# How to calculate average with taking into account only certain values

Tags: matlab, matrix, average, zero

I'm working with a large matrix that contains a lot of zero values.When I transform this matrix from a list table to a cross table, I have more zero values in it.I want to keep all the initial values in it and and supress all the zero values added from matlab for the calculation of the average.Here is an example of what I want to do:

x=

```
0.6000    0.6000    5.0000

0.6000    0.8000    6.0000

0.6000    0.8500         0

0.6000    0.8200         0

0.8000    0.8000    9.0000

0.8000    0.9000    2.0000
```

List table to cross table

```
   NaN    0.6000    0.8000    0.8200    0.8500    0.9000
0.6000    5.0000    6.0000         0         0         0 Average=(5+6+0+0)/4=2,75
0.8000         0    9.0000         0         0    2.0000 Average=(9+2)/2=5,5
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: How do you know which zeros should be excluded and which shouldn't? How do you build the second array from the first?

Answer (score 2):

To compute the mean excluding the zeros you can use

```
result = sum(x(:))/nnz(x);
```

To compute the mean of each row excluding the zeros:

```
result = sum(x.')./sum(x.'~=0);
```

The above solutions assume *all* zeros should be removed from the computations.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to find the mean of a matrix without considering the zeros, try this -

```
%%// Given matrix
x =   [NaN    0.6000    0.8000    0.8200    0.8500    0.9000;
0.6000    5.0000    6.0000         0         0         0;
0.8000         0    9.0000         0         0    2.0000] 

x1 = x;
x1(x==0)=NaN;
rowwise_mean_without_zeros = nanmean(x1,2) %%// mean of rows
whole_mean_without_zeros = nanmean(x1(:)) %%// mean of the whole matrix
```

Output

```
rowwise_mean_without_zeros =

    0.7940
    3.8667
    3.9333


whole_mean_without_zeros =

    2.4882
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are some descriptions that should not be hard to follow. Pick the one that matches your needs.

Assuming that you want to take the average of combinations that contain at least 1 record, I suppose you need more information than just the resulting table.

Either you need to keep an index of which values occur, or you need to look it up in the source table. Alternately, you can also just initialize the table with `NaN` values and only put values there if the combination occurs in the original list.

---

An alternate approach would just be to add a count to the original list, of how often each value occurs and then do the calculations based on that.